# Database normalization - Foreign Keys or Primary Keys

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key, database-normalization

I'm confused about `Foreign Keys` and `Primary Keys`.

I have data normalized in following:

This is table `Users` where are listed all users, Id is `Primary Key`:

```
CREATE TABLE Users
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Name NVARCHAR(60),
    Email NVARCHAR(60),
    Password BINARY(60),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

There is `FreeTime` table, where are stored possibilities of free time (like reading, sport, travelling, etc...) and Id is `Primary Key`:

```
CREATE TABLE FreeTime
(
    Id INT IDENTITY,
    Description NVARCHAR(60),
    PRIMARY KEY (Id)
)
```

Table below `UserFreeTime` store all chosen `FreeTimeId` for each user (each user could select as many free time spending ways as he like):

```
CREATE TABLE UserFreeTime
(
    UserId INT,
    FreeTimeId INT
)
```

So how about `UserFreeTime` table, `UserId` and `FreeTimeId` should be Foreign Keys or Primary Keys? Or I don't need any key for this table at all?

Comment: UserID and FreeTimeID should be the primary key, but individually they should be foreign keys.  This ensures that the combination is unique(Primary key), but also that the data referred to exists (foreign key).

Comment: Normalization does not introduce new columns, eg ids. It replaces a table by projections of it that join to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for something like this.

```
CREATE TABLE UserFreeTime
(
    UserId INT,
    FreeTimeId INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(UserId, FreeTimeId),
    FOREIGN KEY(Userid) REFERENCES Users(Id),
    FOREIGN KEY(FreetimeId) REFERENCES FreeTime(Id)
)
```

The use of the primary key here ensures that a user can have multiple different free time activities but that any pair of user,freetime cannot be repeated.

As a side note, I highly recommend using lower case letters for tables and columns.

Comment: Thank you for an answer, that was what I've looked for. Maybe It's in MySQL recommended to use lower case for tables and columns? I'm working as BI developer (most of time It's querying database, not designing, that's why I'm asking so simple question) with SQL Server in very large company for a few years and almost never seen lower case tables or columns.

Comment: SQL server as in MS SQL Server? Yes lots of people do use upper case there since tables and column names are not case sensitive. When you use mixed case on case sensitive databases it's very hard to remember which letter is upper and which is lower. But lower case is always better because you can tell at a glance what is a column or table and what is an SQL keyword or function call. Leads to more readable code.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question. Let us first understand what is primary key and what is foreign key.

http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/sqlserver/difference-between-primary-key-and-foreign-key

In short.

1. Primary key : If you want to make a column unique in a table and independent of any other table, make it as primary.
2. Foreign key : If you want to make a column dependent on another column in another table, use foreign key constraint

In your case :

1. The user table will have users independent of any other table, so Id column of user table will be primary.
2. The FreeTime table is also independent of any other table because it consists of only freetime details, So make Id column of this table as primary.
3. The UserFreeTime details has two columns UserId and FreeTimeId which are dependent on User table and free tie table because user can not be different from what is present in User table and FreetimeId can not be different from what is present in FreeTime table, So you must make UserId column as foreign key referencing Id Column of User table and FreeTimeId column as foreign key referencing Id column of FreeTime table.

Hope it helps !